# JSON data changes are not saved correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to update a Json data before saving them to the DataBase. I have put the json in a teaxtarea to see the changes and for any update i can see them inside that textarea. But when I do an inspect element on that textarea the value is not changed. How is that even possible? The inspect element of that to be different? When i try to do a save it always get the unchanging. Any ideas on what is happening here? 
Here is how the json is updated:

```
function saveEdit() {
        var id = $("#menu_id").val();
        var updatedTitle = $("#menuTitle").val();
        var json = JSON.parse($('#nestable3-output').text());
        $('#menuName').modal('hide');

        updateObjectField(json, id, updatedTitle);
        document.getElementById('nestable3-output').value = JSON.stringify(json)
    }

    function updateObjectField(obj, id, updatedTitle) {
            obj.forEach((item) => {
                if (item.id === parseInt(id)) {
                    item.content = updatedTitle;
                } else {
                    if(item.children && Array.isArray((item.children))) {
                        updateObjectField(item.children, id, updatedTitle);
                    }
                }
            })

    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe include the HTML so we can see the problem you're facing and assist you with troubleshooting it.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is just a modal that on save button it should update the title and store it into the json

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but the problem was this line:

```
document.getElementById('nestable3-output').value = JSON.stringify(json)
```

I changed to:

```
$('#nestable3-output').text(JSON.stringify(json));
```

And it worked.
If anyone now the reason why it would be great.

Comment: In pure javascript if changing an title instead of document.getElementById('nestable3-output').value = I use document.getElementById('nestable3-output').innerHTML =